# Fiware-Cygnus ERROR: invalid input syntax for type point

Tags: postgresql, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have an attribute in Fiware-Orion with type Point, as follows,

```
{
    "name": "Coords",
    "type": "geo:point",
    "value": "LATITUDE,LONGITUDE"
 }
```

and Cygnus is subscribed to Orion. When Cygnus PostgreSQLSink is receiving the event and it tries to store it in the PostgreSQL database I'm getting the following error

```
WARN sinks.OrionSink: Bad context data (ERROR: invalid input syntax for type point: "[]"
```

What should I use in Fiware-Orion?

Comment: This is being analyzed at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/772